# How to get the Id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I don't know how to get the id from my desired item to update. It goes like this. When I click this button

```
<button class="btn"><a href="bookUpdateUI.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id);?>">Update<a />
```

My page would show the item description that matches the id of the selected item. On my code, it doesn't recognize the id and instead show all the items that has been listed on the db. It also gives me a Notice , Undefined index. What have i done wrong? How can I make this work?

query:

```
public function requestID($id,$table){

     $q="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
     $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
     $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     return $result;
 }
```

bookUpdateUI.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once "../styles/header-menu-out.php"; 
    include "dbconnection.php";

    function __autoload($class){
    include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}
    $code = new codex;  
    try {
            $books = $code->requestID($_POST['id'], "book_info");
            $books = $code->showData("book_info");
    }catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

?>



<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="bookUpdate.php" method="POST" id="edit_form">
    <table>
    <?php foreach ($books as $book_info):?>
    <tr><td><input type="Hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $book_info['id']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $book_info['title']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Author</td><td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $book_info['author']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ISBN</td><td><input type="text" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $book_info['isbn']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Publisher</td><td><input type="text" name="publisher" value="<?php echo $book_info['publisher']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Language</td><td><input type="text" name="language" value="<?php echo $book_info['language']; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Genre</td>
        <td><select name="genre">
                    <option value="<?php echo $book_info['genre']; ?>"><?php echo $book_info['genre']; ?></option>
                    <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
                    <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                    <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
                    <option value="Reserved">Reserved</option>
                    <option value="Instructional Materials">Instructional Materials</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $book_info['quantity']; ?>"/></td></tr>   

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update"/>
        <a href="../bookDeleteUI.php"><input type="button" value="Cancel"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning one thing to `$books`, then stomping that with another thing?

Comment: You should use `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_POST['id']` @YellowBird http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @tadman I don't really know how to call the query. Can you point out on what to do?

Comment: You call the query, capture the result, then run another function and save that into the same variable. Why?

Comment: Is the ID definitely appearing in the URL when you click on the button?

Comment: @middaparka yes. It appears

Comment: @tadman oh okay. I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that you're doing odd things with the `$books` variable, as the URL (unlike the form) isn't a POST, it won't appear in the $_POST super global. (You'll instead have to use `$_GET`, or cover both bases with the `$_REQUEST` super global.)